# Show pricing including or excluding tax based on the customer group

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, customer-group, product-prices

I know that displaying a product price including/excluding tax can be set globally under System->Configuration->Sales->Tax. Is there a way to be more specific, depending on a Customer Group?

Generally I want all prices to display including Tax, but have a Trade Group that need to show prices excluding tax.

I am very green to Magento and by no means 'good' at customising xml, so an idiots guide would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check following function

Mage_Tax_Model_Config class::priceIncludesTax();

this function returns true and false base on system -> config -> tax ->calculation setting ->  Catalog Prices.

you can add condition here by customer group(do not change core file move to local first).

Comment: Very nice hint. +1

Answer (score 0):

Yep it's possible, you can create two customer tax classes under **Sales->Tax->Manage Customer Tax Classes**  Let's call them **Retail Customer** and **Trade Customer**

Now Add Tax Rates under **Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Rates**, provide 0.00 for let's call them **Tax Standard** and **Tax Zero**

Now add Tax rules under **Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Rules**  **Tax Standard** and **Tax Zero** You can then specify Tax Zero to be used with custom group Trade and Tax Standard to be used with retail.

You'll adjust general tax settings under **System->configuration->Sales->Tax**

Screenshot attached for reference.
[image]